# Is Adm. Holdo's hair dyed?

Tags: star-wars, costume, the-last-jedi

[Vice Admiral Amilyn Holdo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Amilyn_Holdo) prominently sports purple hair.

[image]

Is this her natural hair color?

Natural extensions in the answer depending on the correct answer:
Is she wholly human and humans in the Galaxy Far Far Away can have this hair color?   Or is she partly human or not human?   Or does she dye her hair?   Or is there another hair color changing technology?

Comment: I realize this could run afoul of the future works policy, but (1) the film is imminent (2) the answer is unlikely to be in the film.   It's more likely we need to appeal to some support material which may or may not have already been released.

Comment: You know, Greedo dyed his hair first...

Comment: "extensions"  :)

Comment: It died of natural causes.

Comment: @Machavity, yes, regardless of who shot,  everyone can agree that Greedo died first.

Answer (score 30):

## She dyes it

The canon novel [Leia, Princess of Alderaan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Leia,_Princess_of_Alderaan) shows teenage Holdo's frequent dying and eccentric wardrobe choices:

> Amilyn Holdo wafted along, the same slightly glazed expression on her
> face. **Her hair had been dyed pale blue with orange tips**.
>
> 'Apparently Holdo goes her own way'....which was a good reminder that
> it shouldn't matter to Leia what this girl wore or **what colors she
> dyed parts of herself**, or that she always spoke in the same airy
> monotone.
>
> *- Chapter 6*

> **Holdo's hair had been dyed the same green as her cloak**, though at
> least only the cloak had little bells sewn all over it.
>
> -*Chapter 8*

> Holdo, **whose hair had been dyed glittery blue**...
>
> *- Chapter 32*

---

The wikia you cite in your question has the following quote.

> Holdo became disinterested with the peaceful culture of her homeworld, so she expressed herself by **dyeing her hair vibrant colors**, wearing vibrantly-colored clothing, and going on daring escapades.
> <sub>[Amilyn Holdo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Amilyn_Holdo)</sub>

It also states that she is a human female from Gatalenta so it appears she is full human.

Comment: Wow this is a better answer than I was expecting.  I didn't imagine that dyeing all kinds of different colors was going to be a plot point!

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot:   How much time passes between these excerpts?   Like can she change color as often as she wants without damaging her hair, which would indeed point to some hair-dying technology more advanced than we have here in the Milky Way?

Comment: @ThePopMachine I have no idea, NKCampbell found the actual quotes and I haven't seen the film yet.

Comment: See, this confirms that she has dyed it several times, but it never says she dyes it *purple*. There’s a slim chance that purple is her natural hair colour.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite True though this is before the films events. Valorum's answer confirms it was dyed in the film though.

Answer (score 10):

The film's [Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) offers information about her hair colouring routine as well as confirming the reason *why* she dyes her hair pink.

In short, yes, she's human. She dyes her hair using something called *chromomites* and her frequent hair colour changes reflects her heritage, coming from a bohemian planet renowned for its poets and artists.

> **A STRIKING APPEARANCE**
>
> *Holdo doesn't wear the combat khakis and camouflage kit most often
>   spotted in Resistance bases. Instead, **her dyed hair and eye-catching
>   clothing show her fierce devotion to her homeworld of Gatalenta and
>   its independent spirit.** Gatalenta is known across the galaxy for its
>   poetry and the tranquility and compassion of its inhabitants,*

Answer (score 4):

## **Yes. Her Hair Is Dyed.**

Amilyn Holdo dyes her hair various colours according to [her chart on Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Amilyn_Holdo).

According to [an Nerdist article](https://nerdist.com/the-last-jedi-star-wars-amilyn-holdo-luna-lovegood/):

> Anyway, Holdo was different from others on her world: **she wanted to express herself more and did so by regularly dyeing her hair in various bright hues,** wearing bold-colored clothing, decorating her gear with glitter, and generally setting herself apart. She was quirky and often spoke in riddles. Leia called it Holdo-speak.

As far as we know she is a human from the planet Gatalenta. As for hair dying technology, none have been revealed or mentioned as of yet.

Comment: This simply seems to be referencing wookieepedia and a third-party article (written by someone who's read the wookieepedia article) while not offering any direct confirmation.

Answer (score -2):

Vice Admiral Holdo uses chromomites to dye her hair. It says so in the *The Last Jedi Visual Dictionary* on page 40.

Comment: This is already mentioned in Valorum’s answer, and he also provides a quote from the source.