# What species is Vice Admiral Holdo?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, princess-leia

A huge discussion between my friends and I is Holdo's past with Leia, and what Planet Holdo is from. Holdo seems to indicate that her species learned a lot from the 'Rebels' and obviously has had a past of admiration with Princess Leia. What all is know about the purple haired species? Do they have a traditional male/female gender system?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by your last line. Are you asking whether Admiral Holdo’s species (human, by the way) has individuals with male or female genders? Or are you asking whether they have “traditional gender roles,” i.e. was Admiral Holdo expected to be a homemaker rather than an admiral?

Comment: The answers would be, 1) She’s human, 2) humans have male and female genders, but those aren’t the only ones, 3) there’s no evidence that she came from a society with gender roles similar to some traditional groups on Earth, and a lot to suggest she didn’t.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Amilyn_Holdo) says she's human, citing *[Leia, Princess of Alderaan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Leia,_Princess_of_Alderaan)*. The official [*Star Wars* Database](http://www.starwars.com/databank/amilyn-holdo) backs this up.

[image]

My understanding of that scene was that she had learned a lot from Leia, not her species as a whole.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175619/is-adm-holdos-hair-dyed

Comment: @Martha I was not aware of that question. I'm voting to close this one.

Comment: Ahh did not find that one. She dyes it? Thought that character would be more interesting.

Comment: @Rogue Jedi Well her sacrafice shall not be forgotten! Id consider this a duplicate aswell. Thanks!